# Left triangular matrix of the form $D(I + B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices

I want to show that an invertible left triangular matrix $A$ can be represented as $A = D(I + B)$ where $B$ is nilpotent and $D$ is diagonal.
Could I perhaps multiply both sides by $(I + B)^{-1}$ as I know that can be represented as a series? Not sure if that would help.

Comment: what is *"an invertible left triangular matrix"*?  You can simplify thing by assuming $B$ is strictly upper (or lower) triangular which implies $D^{-1}B$ is as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=D+L$ where the diagonal matrix $D$ agrees with $A$ on the diagonal and then $L$ is strictly lower triangular.

Since $A$ is invertible, then so is $D$. Therefore $A=D(I+D^{-1}L)$.

Since $D^{-1}L$ is  strictly lower triangular it is nilpotent, as required.